# how read a specific sheet from a CSV file using read_csv() function of pandas library by passing sheet name as an argument?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i want to read a csv file with the file name, when i pass the sheet name as an argument i am getting an error message.

i tried the following code and it did not work.
`import pandas as pd df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv',sheet_name='sheet 1',header = 1)`
The error message is " read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheet_name' "

Comment: Right. CSV files don't have sheets. Spreadsheets do. Do you have the right type of file?

Comment: Perhaps you want [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use excel_parse instead of parse_CSV , because CSV is a comma separated text file, which does not contain multiple sheets.

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile('path_to_file.xls')
sheet1 = xls.parse(0)

# above will give you first sheet

sheet1 = xls.parse(1)

#This will give you second sheet
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be as follows:

```
file = pd.read_excel('data.csv', sheet_name='sheetName')
```

Just use `read_excel` to handle the `csv` file. Good luck~